# Flexible data filter

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, logic

Help please come up with an algorithm, I do not go to create a complex sample with two or more parameters.

The problem is that, in the table there is a field that can contain `item1 or item2`, but there are two mandatory arguments and the algorithm should vyberat between these two, but so he should look like a match that may be suitable for other criteria of the same data set .

Please help, I'm stuck at this point.
Finding according to the criteria I have coming out and challenging - no.

For example, data and results:
[image]

At the moment I have three tables:

1. Disciplines;
2. Specializations;
3. Discipline_specializations.

which look like this

```
+-----------+  +---------------+  +---------------------------------------------------+
|disciplines|  |specializations|  |             discipline_specializations            |
+----+------+  +---------------+  +----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| id | name |  | id |   name   |  | id | discipline_id | specialization_id | priority |
+----+------+  +----+----------+  +----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Please help, I have simply no idea how to implement it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues here.

The first is storing the data. `item3 or item4` is normalized, so you should break those out to separate disciplines with the same priority (if I've understood your example).

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|             discipline_specializations            |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| id | discipline_id | specialization_id | priority |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  1 | item1         | object1           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  2 | item2         | object1           |        2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  3 | item3         | object1           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  4 | item4         | object1           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  5 | item5         | object2           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  6 | item4         | object2           |        2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  7 | item2         | object2           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  8 | item1         | object2           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
|  9 | item1         | object3           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 10 | item3         | object3           |        2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 11 | item6         | object3           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 12 | item5         | object3           |        3 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 13 | item2         | object4           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 14 | item1         | object4           |        2 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 15 | item4         | object4           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
| 16 | item5         | object4           |        1 |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------+
```

The second problem is querying. What you're looking for is specializations with all the requisite disciplines. MySQL doesn't have an INTERSECT operator, but we can mimic it with IN statements. So this would be the query to find specializations matching one discipline ...

```
select * from specializations s
where s.specialization_id in ( select ds.specialization_id
                               from  discipline_specializations ds
                               where ds.discipline_id = 'item1' )    ;
```

And this would be the query to find specializations matching four disciplines ...

```
select * from specializations s
where s.specialization_id in ( select ds.specialization_id
                               from  discipline_specializations ds
                               where ds.discipline_id = 'item1' )
and    s.specialization_id in ( select ds.specialization_id
                               from  discipline_specializations ds
                               where ds.discipline_id = 'item2' )
and    s.specialization_id in ( select ds.specialization_id
                               from  discipline_specializations ds
                               where ds.discipline_id = 'item3' )
and    s.specialization_id in ( select ds.specialization_id
                               from  discipline_specializations ds
                               where ds.discipline_id = 'item4' )
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I sought this same result but a different method, the problem is that in those areas where there is a condition `OR`, necessarily Select is selected that one thing. This example does not satisfy `one request`, look closely, the `first query` no returns `Object2`.

How it is achieved such a result?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean about `OR` condition. Please provide sample input and output to explain this. Even better would be if you could explain your business rules instead of expecting us to infer them from some obscure data. Perhaps as a matrix? I realize English is not your native language but we can only help you if you are clear about your requirements.

Comment: I mean, why does `[item1,item2,item3,item4]` return `object1` but not `object4`? What's the rule for that?

Comment: Thank you for understanding! `[item1,item2,item3,item4]` so the same will return Object4.
See the example simpler:
Any student who wants to enroll in a specialty cocoa. What would you do, it must pass certain exams. There is a list of specialties (our objects) and discipline in which the student wants to pass the exam (our items).
There is a list of subjects on which you need to pass the exam, which would act on a particular profession.
For example a student wants to enroll in the Faculty of Mathematics, to do this he must pass these exams:

Comment: Mathematic:
1. Native language;
2. Mathematic;
3. English language or History.

Psychology:
1. Native language;
2. Biology;
3. History or Mathematic;

But the same has the faculty of history that would do it, you must pass the following exams
History:
1. Native language;
2. History;
3. English language or Geography.

Comment: When choosing a Native language, mathematic, history, english language. I get the faculties of mathematics and history. That is, high class appropriate response to this request, and therein lies my problem. There should be two basic subject and one subject or, but as the same if my request is suitable for at least three objects, I should get them.

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem:

```
SELECT d.name as discipline_name, s.name as specialization_name
FROM pqh1s_enrolle_disciplines d
LEFT JOIN pqh1s_enrolle_discipline_specializations ds ON ds.discipline_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN pqh1s_enrolle_specializations s ON s.id = ds.specialization_id
WHERE d.id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ds.priority) = 2
```